# PyCharm не видит venv

Tags: python, pycharm, venv

Создаю новый проект в PyCharm через ide - все ок. Создаю через терминал - создается, активируется (в терминале PyCharm тоже - все устанавливается и нужные модули). Захожу в PyCharm -  в списке интерпретаторов нового окружения нет.

Comment: У вас места в вопросе не хватает? Не нужно сокращать PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

1. В разделе настроек `Project: <ИМЯ ВАШЕГО ПРОЕКТА>/Python interpreter` нажмите на `Add interpreter/Add local interpreter`:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. В открывшемся окне выберите флажок `Existing`, и нажмите на кнопку `...`:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В окне выбора файла выберите исполняемый файл `python` в каталоге вашего venv (в Windows путь такой: `<ПУТЬ К ВАШЕМУ VENV>\Scripts\python.exe`)

Должно работать.